# Identify which directory is being accessed by a program

Tags: download

I am running some code using a program to download few files.I see that my available free space in C-drive is decreasing rapidly, but I am not sure to which directory are the files being downloaded to, inside the C drive.

Is there a way to identify this directory?

Comment: There are hundreds of tools that will provide a visual representation of your used space and report the usage of ever folder on your system.  have you tried one of those tools?

Comment: resmon will show disk activity including file and folder names

Comment: I did not know what to google. The terms i used for googling were giving me irrelevant microsoft links. That is why I posted the question here. Could you please name one such tool to me?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Yorik

edit: I use windows and seems like resmon is only for linux

Comment: [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx): "Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity."

Comment: For disk utils, google "treemap disk util"

Comment: Use Windows' Search to find the files?